# The Runner of type Shell don't work: Job failed (system failure): preparing environment:

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

**1- Environment:**

- Gitlab-CE
- GitLab 13.2.1 (b55baf593e6)
- GitLab Shell 13.3.0
- GitLab Workhorse v8.37.0
- GitLab API v4
- Ruby 2.6.6p146
- Rails 6.0.3.1
- PostgreSQL 11.7
- Debian GNU / Linux 10 server (buster)

**2- .gitlab-ci.yml file:**

```
before_script:
  - echo "--------- STARTING WORK ------------"

job_homologacao:
   only:
     - homologation
   script:
     - cd /home/ati/
     - mkdir test
     - echo "got here"

job_producao:
   only:
     - master
   script:
     - cd /home/ati/test/
     - echo "got here"
```

**3- Error presented when the runner is executed:**
Running with gitlab-runner 13.2.1 (efa30e33) on runner with Akx_BvYF shell
Preparing the "shell" performer
Using Shell executor ...
Preparing environment
Running on hermes ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: exit status 1. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information

**4- correction attempts:**
I read and executed all the procedures contained in the codumentation:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/README.html#job-failed-system-failure-preparing-environment
- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I was erroneously editing the file `.bash_logout` located inside my Home `/home/ati/`

Gitlab when installing `gitlab-runner` create a Home for it in `/home/gitlab-runner/`

I just had to comment on the contents of the `/home/gitlab-runner/.bash_logout` file for the job to work.

Comment: I renamed the file to .bash_logout_bkp. Found this way to be easier.

Comment: I wish they(gitlab) add this bit in their documentation on [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading)

Comment: Ah! definitely saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

If your runner is on Ubuntu 20.04, check this out: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26605

Solution:

```
sudo rm /home/gitlab-runner/.bash_logout
```

Comment: no such file exists in mine. k8s environment. runners helm chart :0.31

Answer (score 6):

First find out home directory for gitlab runner.

```
$ ps aux | grep gitlab-runner
/usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /var/lib/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner
```

Now, check `.bash_logout` exist or not.

```
$ ls -lah /var/lib/gitlab-runner/
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  4 gitlab-runner root          4.0K Dec  1 02:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 42 root          root          4.0K Nov 11 03:29 ..
-rwxr--r--  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   30 Dec  1 02:53 .bash_logout
drwxr-xr-x  2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 4.0K Dec  1 02:26 .terraform.d
drwxrwxr-x  3 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 4.0K Nov 11 03:23 builds
```

At last, open `.bash_logout` file and comment out all lines and save it.

```
 $ vim /var/lib/gitlab-runner/.bash_logout
 # ~/.bash_logout: executed by bash(1) when login shell exits.

 # when leaving the console clear the screen to increase privacy

 #if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
 #    [ -x /usr/bin/clear_console ] && /usr/bin/clear_console -q
 #fi
```

ps: Originally answer was given by [Jonathan Allen
Jonathan Allen (@sc_jallen)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26605) on gilab-runner issues.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I was also hit by this bug.
Removing `.bash_logout` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check these?

- Debian users should use APT pinning, because a native package called gitlab-ci-multi-runner is available in Debian Stretch and by default, when installing gitlab-runner, that package from the official repositories will have a higher priority.
- Also, be sure to disable SKEL when installing GitLab Runner: set the environment variable GITLAB_RUNNER_DISABLE_SKEL to `true` before you install the package.

For details on both, see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#apt-pinning